# How to drop sysdate -50 partitions in zabbix in mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partitioning

I am not a dba or plsql developer and I am trying to drop old partitions in mariadb which keeps zabbix data. Basically I have to create store-procedure which has to drop old partitions in the given table.

After this procedure executed table has to keep last 50 days partitions in it. And the table partitions range by hourly so after the procedure executed partition count should be 50*24=1200.

Or can I write sql statement which obtains "alter table drop partition" statement in it?

Test Table details(same as original table);

```
   desc histtest;
    +--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field  | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | itemid | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | clock  | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0       |       |
    | value  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
    | ns     | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0       |       |
    +--------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Procedure should keep max sysdate -50 data.
Partitions created by hourly

Parititon Names;

```
    | p201803250200  | (think as first partition has data)
    | p201803250300  |
    | p201803250400  |
   ...     
    | p201807251700  |(think as last partition has data)
```

Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Redhat Linux 7

Comment: Time-series partitioning discussed here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: This is not work for me because I am trying to find out how to create a procedure delete old partitions which are older than sysdate -50

Comment: Can you deduce "older" from the partition name?  That's what I do.  Or count the number of partitions, then toss the oldest, again based on name.

Comment: See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213220/how-to-drop-sysdate-50-partitions-in-zabbix-in-mariadb

Comment: yes I can, with select statement but the thing is, after reach to the partition data ,which I want to drop, I think I have to create multiple "alter table drop partition" statement that is the point that I am dealing it now.

Comment: Again, my link addresses that.  But it does it only one at a time.  Run the script twice an hour, it will eventually catch up _without_ having to write a loop in the SP.